# Find one line and get the next lines

Tags: python, return, find, line

With this code I get the full line which includes `Name`. But I need to get this line AND the next 2 lines. I have no clue how I can do this.

```
def daten(s): 
for i in s:  
       if i.find('Name') >= 1:
             daten = i
             return daten
```

Example:

```
AAA 
Name 
CCC 
DDD
EEE
```

I want to get `Name`, `CCC`, and `DDD`

Comment: What type is `s`?

Comment: The code provided does not find `Name` in the sample data.  (Also it has an indentation syntax error.)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] your question to include a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please include the expected output and the copy-paste the actual output. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution - if `s` is a file:

```
def daten(s):
    with open(s, 'r') as f: lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for i,line in enumerate(lines): 
        if 'Name' in line: return lines[i:i+3]
```

It searches for the word 'Name' in any of the lines and if find it - returns a list with the word and the two words following.

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with a file?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I supposed it - the sample input looks like a file... - But you are right, just edited my answer to be more specific!

Answer (score 0):

You can make `s` an iterator if it isn't already one, and then call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to get the next two lines after the line containing `'Name'`:

```
def daten(s): 
   s = iter(s)
   for line in s:  
       if line.startswith('Name'): # or more generally: if 'Name' in line: ...
            return [line, next(s), next(s)]
   else:
       raise SomeException
```

If there isn't any line containing name, or there are no lines following the line starting with `'Name'`, you'll get an exception.

Comment: Using `startswith` doesn't match behavior of original code (which may not be what is wanted, but still...)

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is a list, then this would match what your code does but return the desired elements:

```
def daten(s):
    for i,d in enumerate(s):
        if d.find('Name')>=0:
            return s[i:i+3]
```

Note that this

- doesn't work on your example data, but then neither did your code
- doesn't return anything if nothing is found, but neither did your code